# Android Tag Functionality Customization

Tags: java, android

In my application i am giving spannable to different word of single edit text, for that i am storing start and end position of different position on which i need to apply span method.

like this i have used `setChips` method

```
public void setChips() {
        // split string wich comma
        Log.i("FinalData", finaldata + " " + FPos.size() + " " + LPos.size());
        SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder(finaldata);

        for (int i = 0; i < FPos.size(); i++) {

            Log.i("Pos", " " + FPos.get(i) + " " + LPos.get(i));

            LayoutInflater lf = (LayoutInflater) this
                    .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            TextView textView = (TextView) lf.inflate(R.layout.chips_edittext,
                    null);

            int f=FPos.get(i);
            int l=LPos.get(i);

            if(!chipflag){
                //l++;
            }

            textView.setText(finaldata.substring(f,l)); // set
            setFlags(textView, finaldata.substring(f,l)); // set
            // capture bitmapt of genreated textview
            int spec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
            textView.measure(spec, spec);
            textView.layout(0, 0, textView.getMeasuredWidth(),
                    textView.getMeasuredHeight());
            Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(textView.getWidth(),
                    textView.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(b);
            canvas.translate(-textView.getScrollX(), -textView.getScrollY());
            textView.draw(canvas);
            textView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            Bitmap cacheBmp = textView.getDrawingCache();
            Bitmap viewBmp = cacheBmp.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
            textView.destroyDrawingCache(); // destory drawable
            // create bitmap drawable for imagespan
            BitmapDrawable bmpDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(viewBmp);
            bmpDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, bmpDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(),
                    bmpDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight());
            // create and set imagespan
            ssb.setSpan(new ImageSpan(bmpDrawable), FPos.get(i),
                    LPos.get(i), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                        chipflag = false;

        }
        testedt.setText(ssb);
        // setSelection(data.length());


    }
```

For this i am storing each start and end position in Integer ArrayList , Now for example if user change any value on edit text , on that time that position is not going to work, which is obvious, I want to maintain position when user change value of edit text, it will be my pleasure if any one can help